# How to solve JavaScript heap out of memory on prime number exercise

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue understanding this issue i'm having.
I'm trying to find the prime numbers that were used to make this number **992,474,117**

to do that i applied the following code:

```js
function primeFactorsTo(max)
{
    var store  = new Array(max), i, j, primes = new Array(max);
    for (i = 2; i <= max; ++i) 
    {
        if (!store [i]) 
          {
            primes.push(i);
            for (j = i << 1; j <= max; j += i) 
            {
                store[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

primeFactorsTo(992474117)
```

When i run this code i get a >>FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory<<

I saw a few solutions where i have to apply a bigger old space size with

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 yourFile.js
```

but still nothing working. What could be the issue? how to understand it?
Appreciate the help

Comment: You should initialize `primes` with `[]`, not `new Array(max)`. Also declare `i` and `j` with `var` or `let`. Also you only really need primes up to `Math.sqrt(max) + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should initialize the `primes` array as an empty array at the start
2. You only need to loop up to the square root of the number.
3. Once you find a prime factor, keep dividing the number by it until it is no longer divisible to obviate the need for the `store` array.

```js
function primeFactorsTo(max)
{
    var primes = [];
    for (i = 2; i * i <= max; ++i) 
    {
        if(max % i === 0){
          primes.push(i);//found prime factor
          while(max % i === 0) max /= i;
        }
    }
    if(max > 2) primes.push(max);//largest prime factor
    return primes;
}

console.log(primeFactorsTo(992474117));
```